# Google sign-in to Firebase Authentication with two separate and private GSuite organizations

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, google-workspace

I have a GSuite organization that has a private Android app published through Google Admin Console. That organization has a Firebase authentication project setup and the users are able to sign in through the Google SignOn provider in my app.

For business reasons, we created a separate GSuite organization. We don't want various things available to the 2nd organization users, but we do want the private app available to them. This was easy to do by locking down the internal app and sharing the private app to the 2nd GSuite org in the Google Admin Console. So now we have a private app that is downloadable only to people signed into those organizations in the Play Store.

However, only GSuiteOrg-1 can sign into the Firebase authentication. Sharing the app didn't make the Firebase authentication work for GSuiteOrg-2.

What settings or implementation will I need in order to make it so that GSuiteOrg-2 can also sign in?

Right now, when I try to sign in with a user from GSuiteOrg-2, I get this stack trace in Android Studio:

```
E/AuthUI: A sign-in error occurred.
c.b.a.a.f: Code: 12500, message: 12500: 
    at c.b.a.a.r.b.e.a(GoogleSignInHandler.java:110)
    at com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.idp.SingleSignInActivity.onActivityResult(SingleSignInActivity.java:128)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7472)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4590)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4639)
    at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:49)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1977)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6936)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:870)
```

Comment: By the way, through other searches, I've seen that the E/AuthUI error code 12500 can mean a variety of things, so that hasn't pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I paid for Google Cloud support and they told me that there is not a way to share firebase project authentication across two organizations. So, to accomplish both organizations being able to login I used two appIds via [build product flavors](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants). That way I could specify a different firebase authentication project for each build flavor, one firebase configuration and google-services.json file for each organization.